# How to print index number but not for service product qweb?

Tags: odoo

I need to print index number in qweb for line items. But if product type is service product, i must not print index number for that line item alone.

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
<tbody class="sale_tbody">
<t t-set="i" t-value="0"/>
<t t-foreach="doc.order_line" t-as="line">
    <tr>
        <t t-if="line.product_id.type != 'service'">
            <t t-set="i" t-value="i+1"/>
        </t>
        <td>
            <span t-esc="i"/>
        <td/>

    </tr>
</t>
</tbody>
```

You can modify the code according to the requirement.

Comment: Thanks@himanshu, but if I'm having first and third product as consumable, second product as service then i need to print first product with a serial no 1 and third product with a serial number 2.

Comment: Yes above code will work with that condition.As you can see i'm incrementing the value if product is not service type. You can also check another condition if you want to display index for non service products.

Comment: I'm getting 1  0  1 as serial numbers for line items.

Comment: <t t-set="i" t-value="0"/> this code must be declared above for loop. Please paste your code in your question.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. As you said, i set t-value to zero before for each then it worked. Thank you so much @himanshu